# Is it possible to develop our own desired type of window for an application in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I had developed an application in JavaFx. My application appeared in a default type of window, that is like the window in which the explorer(My computer) is opening.

But look at softwares like Avast antivirus, Advanced System care, C-cleaner, they have their own window. I think that it is developed by them for their software. I need to develop such a window of my own for my application. Is it possible in JavaFx ?

StageStyle.UTILITY is acceptable for me, but it doesn't have a minimize button. Is it possible to add a minimize button ? If not, suggest me some other ways ?

Comment: @jewelsea That was what I looking for. But I don't used FXML since, so will suggest me some other links or, if possible give me some tutorials.

Comment: [Oracle's Ensemble sample application](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html), referenced in the answer to the possible duplicate question, does not use FXML, study its source code.